# rspec assert_equal no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
undefined method 'assert_equal' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x8d6f75c>
```

gem list

```
bundler (1.3.5)
diff-lcs (1.2.3)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
test-unit (2.5.4)
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require './lib/checkout.rb'
require './lib/product.rb'
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run :focus
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `object.should eq('foo')` or `expect(object).to eq('foo')` instead. As a side note, `object.should == 'foo'` will give you a Ruby warning when running with the `-w` flag.

Also, this is an assumption answer since you didn't give us any actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than change all your lines in a spec file you can add these at the top

```
 require_relative '../spec_config'
```

and in that file put:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :minitest
end
```

because minitest has assert_equal method. Sorry I'm so late but I was just looking for answer myself to something and just happened to see this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `object.should == "something"`. Here `object` means the object you want to test.